# in struts how do you set the id property for html:hidden

Tags: jsp, struts

I want to put a hidden input onto my html form and am doing so with the following struts tag:

```
<html:hidden property="currentPage" value="page1"></html:hidden>
```

which renders this html:

```
<input type="hidden" value="page1" name="currentPage">
```

How do I set the id property on the html element?  So I want the html to be rendered like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="page1" name="currentPage" id="currentPage">
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
<html:hidden property="currentPage" value="page1" styleId="currentPage"></html:hidden>
```

Comment: In the end I couldn't get this working.  Are you sure this works ?

Comment: Works for me.. the styleId will be converted to HTML id attribute